# What's a regular expression for several occurrences of a string followed by underscore and number?

Tags: regex, mel

Is there a regular expression that matches several (one or more) occurrences of a specific string followed by underscore and number, followed by single underscore and a completely arbitrary string.

For example, if a specific string is "BLAH", I am looking to extract `BLAH_45435_BLAH_6787_BLAH_454335` 
from
 `BLAH_45435_BLAH_6787_BLAH_454335_ThisIs_My_name`.

It is safe to assume that the whole input does not include empty spaces (it is a name of a Maya object). The language implementation is Mel in Maya.

Comment: how do you define "several"

Comment: "several" means one or more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
(?:((?:^|_)BLAH_[0-9]+)+)
```

#### [Working Demo](http://regex101.com/r/jD5aM8)

Answer (score 0):

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://regex101.com/r/cU9eS4)

Try this Regex:

```
/(BLAH_+|[0-9]+_)+/
```